# Графический редактор для создания изображений к сайту

Tags: графика

Подскажите графический редактор.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не относится к программированию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [GIMP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) - растровый графический редактор с частичной поддержкой работы с векторной графикой.

PS - к тому же и кроссплатформенный  :)